# Using language specific variables inside section URL settings

Tags: localization, url, sections, language

When i use some kind of variable in url settings of section, it always uses default language version of this variable.

For example, blog has two languages, english (default) and german. If i use these settings in URL settings for single post section, in german version:

`{{craft.entries.section('archive').one().uri}}/{slug}`

It returns english (default, not german) version o archive section uri.

Is it expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe include the `.site` in your query `craft.entries.section('archive').site('YOUR_SITE_HANDLE').one()`

What is the section type of your "Archive" entry ? If its a single, maybe it will be more effective to write the handle down manually instead of doing a Query every time.

Note: You can also use `.siteId()` instead of `.site()`